# Dev Containers Extension: `userEnvProbe is taking longer than 2 seconds. Process not found.`

Tags: docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, podman, vscode-devcontainer

Currently, attempting to move from using `Docker` to `Podman` when building an image. I can building the container fine in the CLI but I run into trouble when trying to use the `.devcontainers` extension on `VS-Code`. I'm getting the following error:

```
[27274 ms] Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /temp/backup
[27517 ms] [21:15:20] Started initializing default profile extensions in extensions installation folder. file:///root/.vscode-server/extensions
[27583 ms] [21:15:20] ComputeTargetPlatform: linux-x64
[27610 ms] [21:15:20] Completed initializing default profile extensions in extensions installation folder. file:///root/.vscode-server/extensions
[27675 ms] [21:15:20] ComputeTargetPlatform: linux-x64
[27853 ms] Container server: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[27862 ms] Start: Run in container: # Test for /root/.gitconfig and git
[27863 ms] userEnvProbe is taking longer than 2 seconds. Process not found.
[27883 ms] 
[27883 ms] 
[27884 ms] Start: Run in container: # Copy /Users/david.dsilva/.gitconfig to /root/.gitconfig
[27888 ms] Error: unexpected end of parent stream
        at So.destroy (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:106773)
        at So.write (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:107514)
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:109617
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:95001
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:97674
        at Object.cb (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:104092)
        at c (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:102318)
        at /Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:24:102465
        at s (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:27:5371)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/david.dsilva/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.304.0/dist/extension/extension.js:27:5541)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[27888 ms] Container server terminated (code: 139, signal: null).
[27924 ms] 
[27924 ms] 
[27925 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p '/tmp/devcontainers-04490ea3-c94e-49a0-8331-2568d6056a941692652492684' && cat > '/tmp/devcontainers-04490ea3-c94e-49a0-8331-2568d6056a941692652492684/env-loginInteractiveShell.json' << 'envJSON'
[27961 ms] 
[27961 ms] 
[27962 ms] Start: Run in container: # Cleaning up git config
[27969 ms] Port forwarding connection from 52918 > 40577 > 40577 in the container.
[27969 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node -e 
[27973 ms] [21:15:21] No uninstalled extensions found.
[28065 ms] 
[28066 ms] 
[28066 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --global --replace-all credential.helper '!f() { /root/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-8af35539-abf9-4831-a6bb-5786d37bcba1.js git-credential-helper $*; }; f' || true
[28144 ms] 
[28144 ms] 
[28534 ms] Port forwarding 52918 > 40577 > 40577 stderr: Connection established
[28569 ms] Port forwarding connection from 52921 > 40577 > 40577 in the container.
[28569 ms] Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794/node -e 
[28599 ms] [21:15:21] [127.0.0.1][ab28e5f0][ManagementConnection] New connection established.
[28657 ms] [21:15:21] Log level changed to info
[29490 ms] Port forwarding 52921 > 40577 > 40577 stderr: Connection established
[30492 ms] Port forwarding 52921 > 40577 > 40577 stderr: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
[30492 ms] Port forwarding 52918 > 40577 > 40577 stderr: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
```

Not sure what's causing the segmentation issue, but I think it's related to `userEnvProbe`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say this is a "fix", but I at least I got past the error. I think there's something wrong with my old default WSL distro. It was set to "Ubuntu-20.04", and I fixed the problem by changing it to "docker-desktop". After that, my dev container loaded properly. I'm going to try playing with my distros and see if I can come up with a better answer.

[image]

I also want to create a link out to [this closed GH issue in the MS repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8823). It's quite annoying that they closed that issue, but there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Bounty answer (Docker Desktop, no podman):

The error message `userEnvProbe is taking longer than 2 seconds. Process not found.` can occur in a Visual Studio Code (VS Code) environment while using Docker Desktop. That error is typically associated with the initialization phase where VS Code tries to probe the environment settings within the container.

Check first you have compatible versions of VS Code and Docker Desktop (as [`microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 6024](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6024) illustrates with VS Code Version 1.63.0 and Docker Desktop version 4.3.0).
In some cases, the dev container startup hangs, and the error message `userEnvProbe is taking longer than 10 seconds` is displayed. That suggests there might be a delay in the initialization process which could be similar to your `2 seconds` error message.

If you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) along with Docker Desktop, there might be issues related to SSH setup that cause the `userEnvProbe` delay ([issue 6028](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6028)). You need to make sure the SSH agent setup is correct and there is no waiting for user input in your shell's startup scripts.

Sometimes the error occurs during the "Setting up Remote-Containers" phase ([issue 7005](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7005)). That could be related to incorrect configurations or issues with the startup scripts within the dev container.
In some situations, the error message advises avoiding waiting for user input in your shell's startup scripts. That indicates that there might be a prompt or some interactive element in your startup scripts that is causing the delay.

Double-check that your [`devcontainer.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container) and Docker configuration files are set up correctly. Any misconfigurations could lead to issues with the `userEnvProbe`.

---

[mike01010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480118/mike01010) also propose in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948755/dev-containers-extension-userenvprobe-is-taking-longer-than-2-seconds-process/77295159#comment136368708_77295159):

> I am also seeing this. It is after this command: Run in container:
>
> ```
> for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { \
>   echo $pid ; \ 
>   readlink /proc/$pid/cwd || echo ; \
>   readlink /proc/$pid/ns/mnt || echo ; \
>   cat /proc/$pid/stat | tr "
> ```

This command is likely being used for diagnostic or logging purposes within the container to gather and output information about the processes running inside it. This might be a part of troubleshooting or monitoring procedures to understand the container's behavior or to identify potential issues.

The information gathered by this command could help in identifying any abnormal behaviors, incorrect configurations, or other issues within the container that might be leading to the `userEnvProbe` error.
For instance, examining the current working directory, mount namespace, and process status of all processes within the container could reveal discrepancies or unexpected states that might be clues to the underlying problem.

---

Original answer (podman-related):

When using [podman with VSCode](https://blog.while-true-do.io/podman-configure-vscode-for-containers/), check if:

- everything has been updated (as mentioned in `microsoft/vscode-remote-release` issue 6024)
- the settings are properly adjusted, like the `Docker: Host` value to `unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock` (replace 1000 with your user id, which can be obtained by running the `id -u` command in a terminal). And change the `Docker: Docker Path` value to `/usr/bin/podman​`.
- the Podman service and socket are enabled (see [Remote container development with VS Code and Podman](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/02/14/remote-container-development-vs-code-and-podman#:%7E:text=Login%20as%20the%20new%20,since%20you%27ll%20need%20it%20shortly), it that applies in your case): `podman system service -t 0 & systemctl enable --now --user podman.socket​`.

While those checks might not directly address the `userEnvProbe` timeout error, they could help ensure that your VS Code and Podman setup is correctly configured, which might mitigate the error.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. It's not a podman problem, because I'm not using podman. I'm using Docker Desktop.

Comment: @AlexDresko What do you mean? The question starts with "attempting to move from using Docker to Podman when building an image". Why put a bounty on a question which is not about your problem?

Comment: @AlexDresko Anyhow, I have edited the answer to focus on Docker Desktop.

Comment: im also seeing this. it is after this command: ```Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink /proc/$pid/cwd || echo ; readlink /proc/$pid/ns/mnt || echo ; cat /proc/$pid/stat | tr "```

Comment: @mike01010 Interesting, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC in my case, i had docker desktop open, but i was opening a project that was a remote devcontainer to an actual linux host.  after killing docker desktop (wsl --shutdown) and re-opening, it worked fine.  i think vscode may doing something if it detects docker desktop, and if your devcontainer isnt one that actually runs under docker desktop - there may be issues.

Comment: @mike01010 OK. The Visual Studio Code Dev Containers extension could have some unforeseen side-effect indeed.